# Inserting text to existing text within brackets

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a file similar to this:

```
[one]
[two]
[three]
[four = something]
```

I want to add `/mame/` in front of the word in square brackets except when there’s an `=` sign on the line

So the above will be

```
[/mame/one]
[/mame/two]
[/mame/three]
[four = something]
```

I’ve tried this:

```
sed -i 's|\[*]|\mame/\]|g' afile
```

But everything is the wrong way round, the `/mame/` is added to the end of the existing word

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

A few things:

- `*` in regex is a quantifier; if you want behavior similar to the shell wildcard you need `.*` (any single character, zero or more times)
- `.*` matches greedily, so if you want to exclude things like `=` as well as the closing `]` you need to do so explicitly - that's where you need *non*-literal `[` and `]`
- `m` does not need to be escaped on either the LHS (regex pattern) or RHS (replacement)
- you need a capture group if you want to re-use (aka *backreference*) the text between the brackets
- you don't need `g` unless you have multiple matches *per line*

So

```
$ sed -r 's|\[([^=[]*)\]|[/mame/\1]|' file
[/mame/one]

[/mame/two]

[/mame/three]

[four = something]
```

---

With Perl (which also has a `-i` in-place mode), you could use lookarounds and lazy (non-greedy) matching:

```
$ perl -pe 's{(?<=\[)([^=]*?)(?=])}{/mame/$1}' file
[/mame/one]

[/mame/two]

[/mame/three]

[four = something]
```

Answer (score 2):

I propose this:

```
sed '/=/!s;^\[;[/mame/;' file
```

Output:

```
[/mame/one]
[/mame/two]
[/mame/three]
[four = something]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simpler in two steps

1. Add mame to all
   `sed -i 's/\[/\[\/mame\//' m.txt`
2. Remove mame from =
   `sed -i 's/\/mame\/\(.* =\)/\1/' m.txt`

or
`sed 's/\[/\[\/mame\//' m.txt | sed 's/\/mame\/\(.* =\)/\1/'`